# Clearing empathy IM client previous conversation

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.10, instant-messaging, empathy

I am using ubuntu Empathy IM client for my Gmail account chatting .Can any one tell me how to clear the previos conversations in the Empathy IM client.I tried right click and clear.But it is clearing temporarily but not permanent.Is there any way to clear that?

Answer (score 2):

The GUI method of clearing previous messages for an account in empathy consists of right clicking a buddy in the contact list, selecting "previous conversations", and subsequently selecting "Edit"->"Clear" in the popup window. Then, select the account you'd like to clear the logs on and confirm deletion of your logs.

Answer (score 1):

Logs for empathy are stored in `/home/<username>/.local/share/Empathy/`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is out of date. See here for later versions of Ubuntu/Empathy: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4283/how-do-i-backup-restore-my-empathy-logs